# Unable to launch welcome page using Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

This is a very common question but i am unable to find its solution. 
I have created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. Its an empty project with no java files.Whenever i try to run it on Tomcat server , it gives me HTTP Status 404 error : The requested resource not found.
The index.html which is the welcome page is inside the WEB-INF folder and content of web.xml is as below

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index.html` should be in the web project root folder, next to `WEB-INF` folder. So, in Eclipse, the folder structure should look like next:

```
MyEclipseProject
    ...
    WebContent
        index.html
        ...
        WEB-INF
            web.xml
```